# Modifying Shader Properties from C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to modify a custom shader's properties form C#.
I'm able to see the properties updating in the inspector, but I don't see the changes reflected in the game unless I manually enter modify the values in the inspector.

Here is the relevant shader code:

```
Shader "UCLA Game Lab/Wireframe/Single-Sided"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Line Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Thickness("Thickness", Float) = 1
        _ValleyDepth("Depth", Range(0, 2)) = 0
        _HeightMap("Heightmap", 2D) = "black" {}
        _Scale("Scale", Range(0, 5)) = 1
        _Mask("Mask", 2D) = "black" {}
        _MaskWidth("Mask Width", Range(0, 120)) = 5
        _MaskHeight("Mask Height", Range(0, 120)) = 10

        [PerRendererData]_TravelX("Travel X", Float) = 0
        _TravelY("Travel Y", Float) = 0

    }

        SubShader
        {
            Pass
            {
                //Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }

                Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
                //ZWrite Off
                LOD 200

                CGPROGRAM
                

                #pragma target 5.0
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"
                #include "UCLA GameLab Wireframe Functions.cginc"
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma geometry geom


                float _ValleyDepth;
                sampler2D _HeightMap;
                float _Scale;
                float3 _WorldPOS;
                float _TravelX;
                float _TravelY;



                float random(float2 uv)
                {
                    return (_ValleyDepth * frac(sin(dot(uv,float2(12.9898,78.233)))*43758.5453123)  );
                }

        // Vertex Shader
        UCLAGL_v2g vert(appdata_base v)
        {

            _WorldPOS = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex); // ben

            //v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * random(v.texcoord);
            v.texcoord *= _Scale;
            v.texcoord.x += _TravelX;
            v.texcoord.y += _TravelY;
            fixed height = tex2Dlod(_HeightMap, float4(v.texcoord.xy, 0, 0)).r;
            v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * height * _ValleyDepth;
            return UCLAGL_vert(v);
        }

        // Geometry Shader
        [maxvertexcount(3)]
        void geom(triangle UCLAGL_v2g p[3], inout TriangleStream<UCLAGL_g2f> triStream)
        {
            UCLAGL_geom(p, triStream);
        }

        // Fragment Shader
        float4 frag(UCLAGL_g2f input) : COLOR
        {
            return UCLAGL_frag(input);
        }

    ENDCG
}
        }
}
```

And here is the c#:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material heightMapX;

    

    public float speedX = 0f;
    public float speedY = 0f;



    Renderer thisRend; //Renderer of our Cube


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        thisRend = GetComponent<Renderer>(); // grab the renderer component on our cube



        //heightMapX.EnableKeyword("_travelX"); 
        heightMapX.SetFloat("_TravelX", speedX);
        heightMapX.SetFloat("_TravelY", speedY);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            speedX += 5f;
            //heightMapX.SetFloat("_TravelX", speedX);
            thisRend.material.SetFloat("_TravelX", speedX);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            speedY -= 5f;
            //heightMapX.SetFloat("_TravelY", speedY);
            thisRend.material.SetFloat("_TravelY", speedY);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried using the [PerRendererData] directive on the shader variables but it didn't help.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post questions!

Answer (score 2):

As Poultryghast mentioned, I'd recommend getting into the habit of using **MaterialPropertyBlocks**, as the performance gains are quite notable.

Here's another link to a more condensed and high-level view article explaining MPBs. https://thomasmountainborn.com/2016/05/25/materialpropertyblocks/

Essentially, what you're looking for is more something along the lines of :

```
private MaterialPropertyBlock myBlock;
private Renderer renderer;
    
public float speedX = 0f;
public float speedY = 0f;
    
void Awake()
{
    myBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock(); // create a new PropertyBlock
    renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>(); // get your current renderer
}
    
void Start()
{
    renderer.GetPropertyBlock(myBlock); // retrieve the renderer's existing Property Block 
                                        // and store it into "myBlock"
    
    myBlock.SetFloat("_TravelX", speedX); // make your value changes in your new PB
    myBlock.SetFloat("_TravelY", speedY);
    
    renderer.SetPropertyBlock(myBlock); // apply your values onto the renderer's existing Block
}
```

From here, you can simply apply this same logic in your `Update()` method.

I'd recommend changing the values inside your if `(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode))` statements, and calling the  `renderer.SetPropertyBlock(myBlock)` at the end of the Update loop.

Either way, I believe this is *a lot more optimized* than going through the `material` everytime, but this has already been pointed out, and the article discusses it at greater lengths ;)

Comment: So I switched to the material property block (thanks for the tip about performance!) and I still have the same issue: updates in inspector...but not in scene, unless I manually change values.

I tried to paste the code but I went over the char limit.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set the material `heightMapX` back to the renderer. Try `thisRend.material = heightMapX` to actually apply the values of the material to the shader.
Also, every time you do this it actually creates a new material which affects performance if you are doing this every frame. It's a little bit advanced but you can solve this problem using MaterialPropertyBlocks and GPU Instancing. [This](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/rendering/part-19/) is a good tutorial if you are interested.

Comment: good catch. I may have been sloppily switching between methods. I tried it out with thisRend.material = heightMapX and still ran into the same issue. I thin switched to using the material property block and am still facing the same issue. Is GPU instancing required to solve this?